# Git Extensions (GitExt) What is the difference between square and circle symbols for commits?

Tags: git-extensions

What is the meaning of the squares and the rare circles as seen in the below git repository screenshot from GitExt?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square ones have tag / branch names pointing at them — though you have disguised that fact by omitting the right side of the diagram from your screenshot.

Comment: - Thanks. Then I think, ideally, we should be having more of those circles than what we have currently. Is there a best practice that we are missing here ?

Comment: On the contrary. But that in any case is way outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: @KaranChadha There is no real best practice here but there is a pattern that we encounter often: more refs/squares in the recent history (because that's where the dev is done) and a lot less in older history (good practice: if you delete the no more useful merged branch refs and prune them in your local repository)